# OPA/Rego execute function for each element of an array

Tags: open-policy-agent, rego

I am new at OPA/Rego and I am trying to write a policy to check if an Azure Network Security Group contains all the rules that I define on an array

```
package sample
default compliant = false
toSet(arr) = {x | x := arr[_]}
checkProperty(rule, index, propertySingular, propertyPlural) = true
{
    object.get(input.properties.securityRules[index].properties, propertySingular, "") == object.get(rule, propertySingular, "")
    count(toSet(object.get(input.properties.securityRules[index].properties, propertyPlural, [])) - toSet(object.get(rule, propertyPlural, []))) == 0
}
existRule(rule) = true
{
    input.properties.securityRules[i].name == rule.name
    input.properties.securityRules[i].properties.provisioningState == rule.provisioningState
    input.properties.securityRules[i].properties.description == rule.description
    input.properties.securityRules[i].properties.protocol == rule.protocol
    checkProperty(rule, i, "sourcePortRange", "sourcePortRanges")
    checkProperty(rule, i, "destinationPortRange", "destinationPortRanges")
    checkProperty(rule, i, "sourceAddressPrefix", "sourceAddressPrefixes")
    checkProperty(rule, i, "destinationAddressPrefix", "destinationAddressPrefixes")
    input.properties.securityRules[i].properties.access == rule.access
    input.properties.securityRules[i].properties.priority == rule.priority
    input.properties.securityRules[i].properties.direction == rule.direction
}
compliant
{
    rules := [
            {
                "name": "name1",
                "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
                "description": "description1",
                "protocol": "*",
                "sourcePortRange": "*",
                "destinationPortRange": "53",
                "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
                "access": "Allow",
                "priority": 1,
                "direction": "Inbound",
                "sourceAddressPrefixes":
                [
                    "xx.xx.xx.xx",
                    "xx.xx.xx.xx",
                    "xx.xx.xx.xx"
                ],
            },
            {
                "name": "name2",
                "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
                "description": "description2",
                "protocol": "*",
                "sourcePortRange": "*",
                "destinationPortRange": "54",
                "sourceAddressPrefix": "*",
                "access": "Allow",
                "priority": 2,
                "direction": "Outbound",
                "destinationAddressPrefixes":
                [
                    "xx.xx.xx.xx",
                    "xx.xx.xx.xx",
                    "xx.xx.xx.xx"
                ]
            }
        ]
    #checks
    existRule(rules[i])
}
```

The issue seem to be that when execute `existRule(rules[i])` if one of the rules match it returns true, don't mather if other rules doesn't
If I replace `existRule(rules[i])` with `existRule(rules[0])` or `existRule(rules[1])`, it return true or false depending on if the rule on that position matchs.

Is there any way to get the result of the execution of `existRule(rules[i])` for all the elements of the array?

I already tried `result := [existRule(rules[i])]` but it only return one element with true

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure! Use a list comprehension and call the function inside of it, then compare the size of the result to what you had before. Given your example, you would replace `existRule(rules[i])` with something like this:

```
compliantRules := [rule | rule := rules[_]
                          existRule(rule)]
                              
count(compliantRules) == count(rules)
```